# Error when using ODCB to access.mdb database on eclipse?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, ms-access

So i have a java project build on eclipse. The code runs fine, but whenever the application has to access the database it says :

```
Unable to access the database
```

This is the only error that eclipse displays... I don't seem to understand where the problem is coming from. I have already imported the odcb driver in the referenced libraries and i have the connector ODCB installed...

The database is a .mdb file...

Here is part of the code...

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); 
final String fileName = "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/centrallab.mdb";
String url =  "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
localConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
localStatement = localConnection.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following things :

1) Can you access the Database from MS Access.

2) Did you configure Microsoft Access ODBC Data Source in the ODBC Administrator within Administrative Tools from your Control Panel,

You can get more info on accessing MS Access Db using Java program in the following [link](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/microsoft-access/jdbc-odbc.html)